# How do I call a built-in parsley validator from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I'm using version parsley js, version 2.0.7. I would like to invoke a built-in `parsley` validator from a custom validator.
For example I would like the attribute `data-parsley-customtype="number"` to behave exactly as  `data-parsley-type="numeric"`.

Is there a way to invoke an already defined validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally analyzed a bit more the source code of the parsley validator and I found out that I can use something like this:

```
return window.ParsleyValidator.validate(value,
window.ParsleyValidator.validators.type("number"));
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to rename the built-in pasley validators?
Why do you want to do that? (just curious)

You can define a new custom validator and redefine the same logic.

Try something like this:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('customValidation', 
    function (value) {
        return true==(/^\d+$/.test(value)) // validates numbers 
    })
    .addMessage('en', 'customValidation', 'Your custom error message');
```

And don't forget to add the attribute to your element:

```
$("#element").attr('data-parsley-customValidation',$("#element").val());
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. I already found the answer `return window.ParsleyValidator.validate(value,
window.ParsleyValidator.validators.type("number"));` . I explained in the comment for Marc why I needed that.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like a great idea (better use a standard when there is one), but you could call `addConstraint` yourself.

E.g. (untested):

```
$('[data-parsley-customtype]').each(function() {
  $(this).parsley().addConstraint('type', 'integer');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. A backend constraint is assigned dynamically from a drop-down, by the authors (CMS application). I want to generate the client side validation based on the selection from the drop-down. I could have a mapping (backend constraint -> parsley constraint) but i would like to avoid this, therefore my question. I thought that maybe there is a way when defining my custom validator to just call some 'validate' function of a built-in validator.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is my example for React. Parsley version:  "parsleyjs": "^2.9.1"

```
import Parsley from 'parsleyjs/dist/parsley.min.js';

export const addCustomValidator = (validatorName, validator) => {
    if(Parsley.hasValidator(validatorName)){
        Parsley.updateValidator(validatorName, validator);
    }else{
        Parsley.addValidator(validatorName, validator);
    }
}
```

#### data-parsley-number

```
addCustomValidator('number', {
        validateNumber: value => {
            return value && typeof value === "number" ? true : false;
        },
        messages: {
            en: "This is a number",
        }
    });
```